# Choose single date per ID based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table containing multiple LoggedDates per ID. However, there is only one currentDate and one entryDate per each ID:

```
ID          LoggedDate  CurrentDate EntryDate    
140960738   6/12/2020   6/16/2020   5/29/2020    
140960738   6/12/2020   6/16/2020   5/29/2020    
140960738   6/16/2020   6/16/2020   5/29/2020    
140960738   6/16/2020   6/16/2020   5/29/2020    
140960780   6/5/2020    6/24/2020   1900-01-01    
140960780   6/5/2020    6/24/2020   1900-01-01    
140960780   6/24/2020   6/24/2020   1900-01-01    
140960780   6/24/2020   6/24/2020   1900-01-01    
140960825   6/3/2020    6/19/2020   6/22/2020    
140960825   6/3/2020    6/19/2020   6/22/2020    
140960825   6/19/2020   6/19/2020   6/22/2020    
140960825   6/19/2020   6/19/2020   6/22/2020    
140960826   5/10/2020   6/2/2020    6/15/2020    
140960826   5/15/2020   6/2/2020    6/15/2020    
140960826   6/15/2020   6/2/2020    6/15/2020    
140960826   6/20/2020   6/2/2020    6/15/2020    
140960826   6/25/2020   6/2/2020    6/15/2020    
140960836   4/15/2020   6/25/2020   6/7/2020    
140960836   5/10/2020   7/2/2020    6/7/2020    
140960836   5/15/2020   6/26/2020   6/7/2020    
140960836   5/30/2020   6/22/2020   6/7/2020    
140960836   6/4/2020    6/24/2020   6/7/2020
```

I need to show a result table that shows a single date per each ID, which combines LoggedDate and CurrentDate based on the following conditions:

1. When there exists a LoggedDate per each ID which equals the EntryDate, show only that row.
   e.g: ID 140960826 has an entry date of 6/15, and 6/15 is listed in the LoggedDate column. So that ID would only return one row with ID, EntryDate, and LoggedDate = 6/15
2. When ID doesn't contain loggedDate whhich equals the EntryDate, then return the min(loggedDate) > EntryDate.
   e.g : ID 140960738 only has to return one row where LoggedDate = 6/12/2020
3. When ID doesn't contain loggedDate which equals the EntryDate, and there is no loggedDate>EntryDate, then return the max(loggedDate)
   e.g: ID 140960836 has to return 6/4/2020 as the loggedDate
4. When EntryDate = '1/1/1900' then return the CurrentDate as Date.

So far, I have tried the following case statement to add an Identifier based on the condition, which would then be used for pulling the result date, but this doesn't work:

```
CASE WHEN EntryDate <> '1900-01-01' AND EntryDate <= LoggedDate
 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LoggedDate)
 WHEN EntryDate <> '1900-01-01' AND EntryDate > LoggedDate
 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LoggedDate)
 WHEN EntryDate = '1900-01-01' THEN 0
 END AS 'Identifier'
```

The result table needs to show as below:

```
ID         ResultsDate  EntryDate    
140960738   6/12/2020   5/29/2020    
140960780   6/24/2020   1900-01-01    
140960825   6/19/2020   6/22/2020    
140960826   6/15/2020   6/15/2020    
140960836   6/4/2020    6/7/2020
```

Need help on solving this

Comment: I don't understand the fourth condition.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, apologies, the third condition should be contingent on if EntryDate <> '1/1/1900'

Comment: . . Thank you for the clarification.  I fixed my answer -- I originally misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmmm . . . You want only one date per user.  That suggests aggregation:

```
select id,
       coalesce(min(case when LoggedDate >= EntryDate then LoggedDate end),
                max(case when EntryDate <> '1900-01-01' then LoggedDate end),
                CurrentDate
               ) as the_date
from t
group by id;
```

This tests the conditions, returning `NULL` if they don't match.  The first is for the first two conditions.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID,
CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE ID = ppal.ID)>0 AND EntryDate <> '1900-01-01' THEN EntryDate
  WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE ID = ppal.ID AND LoggedDate>ppal.EntryDate)>0 AND EntryDate <> '1900-01-01' THEN (SELECT MIN(LoggedDate) FROM tbl WHERE ID = ppal.ID AND LoggedDate>ppal.EntryDate)
  WHEN EntryDate = '1/1/1900' THEN CurrentDate
  ELSE (SELECT MAX(LoggedDate) FROM tbl WHERE ID = ppal.ID) END AS Date
FROM tbl ppal
GROUP BY ID, EntryDate
```